# Whats the fastest way to find a consecutive day list

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

i have an array of vacation dates. These are always going to be weekdays.  Lets say

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[] {"1/8/2010","1/3/2010","1/6/2010","1/7/2010","1/21/2010"}
```

i now have a single input date.  Lets say:

```
DateTime vacationDateToCheck = 1/7/2010;
```

i want to find the vacation set (list of dates) given the set above. In particular, i want the first and last date of the list.

So for example, if i pass in vacationDateToCheck variable (1/7/2010) i would get back

Yes, you are on vacation from 1/6/2010 to 1/8/2010.

If i pass in 1/4/2010 it would return an empty result.

**Here is the kicker.  I want it to factor in weekends and go across weekends.  So if i have a vacation on a friday and on the following Monday, i would want it to include that as one list.**

any suggestions?

Comment: Could you use either ISO 8601 date format or specify the order of the parts?

Comment: Is storing the vacation days as a list of individual days set in stone? It's not the best way and makes this task somewhat more difficult.

Comment: Also, how would you cope with vacation that spans a weekend? Would the weekend days be included in the list as vacation days or would vacation starting in week 1 and ending in week 2 be treated as two separate vacation periods for the purposes of your function?

Comment: @Joey: He's using DateTime, so he isn't actually storing those strings - they will be parsed into DateTime objects, which are easy to sort. It's most likely just to give a concrete example.

Comment: you might wanna specify the date format you're using. To most of the world your example reads "yes you are on vacation from June 1st to August 8th"

Comment: @Lazarus - good point, i would want to have it go across weeks.  So if i was on vacation on Thursday to Tuesday i would want to include the whole list.

Comment: @ooo, if you could store the vacation periods as periods rather than collections of days then this would be sooooo much easier and a much cleaner design for the rest of the app no doubt.

Comment: @Lazarus - i appreciate your point and i have thought about that (and still might refactor and move to that model) but i wanted a short term solution before i am going to have time to change the model.

Comment: @Lazarus - i changed the model (much easier and didn't take as long as i thought)

Comment: @ooo - Glad it was easier than you thought (it nearly always is, and I still have to remind myself of that daily!) and I hope that it's made your problem space much easier to deal with.

Comment: @Lazarus - yup . . sometimes the "quick workaround" becomes more trouble than its worth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll have to sort your array, or at least make a sorted copy if it's important that you keep the order in the original list. If you don't, this isn't going to be easy.

Then, find the index of the element you're checking for. Once you've done that, create a loop going forwards, and one going backwards in your array, and count the date you've reached in the loop if the two dates are consective; otherwise, stop that loop (and do the other loop if you haven't done that already).

This assumes that *all* days in the range you're looking for can be found in the list, including weekends and holidays.

EDIT: If you want to include weekends implictly, you'll have to check the weekday using [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) while iterating over the days. The simplest way to do this is probably to also maintain a variable for the next expected day; every iteration in your loop, you add (or subtract, when moving backwards through the sorted array) one day. If the day you're processing is a Friday (or Monday when moving backwards), add/subtract an additional 2 days to skip the weekend.

Here's the basic idea (not tested, but you should get the point). I'm assuming that you've sorted `dates` already, and that you've found the initial date in your array (at index `i`). For simplicity, I'm also assuming that `vacationDateToCheck` is never a Saturday or Sunday; if it can be either of those, you'll have to adjust accordingly.

```
DateTime expectedDate = vacationDateToCheck.AddDays(1);
if (vacationDateToCheck.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
  expectedDate = expectedDate.AddDays(2);
DateTime startDate = vacationDateToCheck;
DateTime endDate = vacationDateToCheck;
for (int j = i + 1; i < dates.Length; i++) {
  if (dates[i] == expectedDate) {
    endDate = dates[i];
    expectedDate = dates[i].AddDays(1);
    if (dates[i].DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
      expectedDate = expectedDate.AddDays(2);
  } 
  else 
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Iterating the other way is similar, only you add -1 and -2 days instead, and you check if the day of the week is a Monday.

Comment: read the updated question.  i want it to implicitly understand weekends